# How to hook to WH_KEYBOARD for PopupList.Window?

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl

I need to know if F11 is pressed when PopupMenu of TrayIcon is open & terminate program. Do not want RegisterHotKey. Documentation states that "PopupList.Window provides access to the Window handle of the hidden window that processes popup menu messages". So my plan is to intercept keyboard messages to that window, but instead this is what happens:

> Project Project2.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
> 'access violation at 0x00020003: write of address 0x2014fd38'.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
    TForm2 = class(TForm)
        TrayIcon1: TTrayIcon;
        PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
        N11: TMenuItem;
        N21: TMenuItem;
        ImageList1: TImageList;
        procedure PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
private
    function hook(code: Integer; w: WPARAM; p : LPARAM): Lresult stdcall;
public
    { Public declarations }
end;

var
    Form2: TForm2;
    HookID: hhook;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function TForm2.hook(code: Integer; w: WPARAM; p: LPARAM): Lresult stdcall;
begin
    if code < 0 then
    begin
        Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, w, p);
        Exit;
    end;

    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, w, p);
end;

procedure TForm2.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
begin
    HookID := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, @TForm2.hook, 0,
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(PopupList.Window, nil));
end;

end.
```

Comment: The body of your hook can be simplified to `Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, w, p);`

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx()` is not the best way to hook keyboard messages sent to the popup menu. Just subclass the `PopupList.Window` itself, using `SetWindowSubclass()` or `SetWindowLongPtr()`. Or better, just replace the `PopupList` object with a custom object that overrides the `TPopupList.WndProc()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook function is a method of TForm2 and thus has an extra (hidden) self parameter passed. You should place the function outside of TForm2:

```
    TForm2 = class(TForm)
        TrayIcon1: TTrayIcon;
        PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
        N11: TMenuItem;
        N21: TMenuItem;
        ImageList1: TImageList;
        procedure PopupMenu1Popup(Sender: TObject);
    private
    public
        { Public declarations }
    end;

    function hook(code: Integer; w: WPARAM; p : LPARAM): Lresult stdcall;

implementation

function hook(code: Integer; w: WPARAM; p: LPARAM): Lresult stdcall;
begin
    if code < 0 then
    begin
        Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, w, p);
        Exit;
    end;

    Result := CallNextHookEx(0, code, w, p);
end;
```

Comment: Or you can make it into a static class function: `private
    class function hook(code: Integer; w: WPARAM; p : LPARAM): Lresult stdcall; static;`

Comment: And also remove redundant code lines: just call `CallNextHookEx()` always.